# Setting QStyleOptionComboBox.currentText does not have any effect on the drawn widget

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I want to draw a QComboBox inside a delegate, which works fine except that I can't figure out how to draw the inital text that's visible inside the combo box.

The documentation says that `QStyleOptionComboBox.currentText` holds: "the text for the current item of the combo box." but setting the variable does not have any effect.

This is my code:

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
    const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QStyleOptionComboBox comboBoxOption;
    comboBoxOption.rect = option.rect; 
    comboBoxOption.state = option.state;
    comboBoxOption.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
    comboBoxOption.editable = false;
    comboBoxOption.currentText = "CCC"; // This doesn't show up.

    QApplication::style()->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &comboBoxOption, painter);
}
```

Looking at `qwindowsxpstyle.cpp` I don't see where the text of a "real" combo box is drawn since `currentText` is not used inside the `drawComplexControl` method. The only place where it seems to be used for Windows XP style is in `qcommonstyle.cpp` (Line 2107, Qt 4.7.2), but I can't figure out how those two classes play together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you also need to force Qt to draw the combo box label, in addition to the complex control. Try this:

```
QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, &comboBoxOption, painter)
```

If I read the documentation, and source, correctly that might force QStyle to draw a combo box label. It seems odd that you'd have to specify both...but I don't know a whole lot about how Qt styles draw themselves, to be honest.

Comment: No problem! Just further to it though, you know this won't actually give you an editable QComboBox, right? It'll just paint the pixels for a combo box on screen. If you want a fully editable combo box, you should look at QItemDelegate::createEditor(). I've used it before to implement inline-editing of items in a QTreeView. It works pretty well.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `createEditor()` as well. I was attacking the problem that the QComboBox should always be visible, not only in edit mode. Painting it is not the best solution. `QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor()` does this job!